# How to write to a text file sequentially in the same text line?

Tags: external-files

I would like to write a text file from a LaTeX document with the following format:

A,C,D,B

where A, C, D and B are to be written into the text file from different places of the LaTeX document. Thus, I cannot at once write

A,C,D,B

but

A,

and then

C,

and so on.

Could you please help me?

Thanks in advance,

Paul

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accumulate in a token register and write them all together

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtoks\mywritetoks
\newwrite\mywritefile
\def\mywrite#1{%
\expandafter\ifx\expandafter\vadjust\the\mywritetoks\vadjust
\global\mywritetoks{#1}%
\else
\global\mywritetoks\expandafter{\the\mywritetoks,#1}%
\fi
}

\begin{document}

\mywrite{A}

\mywrite{C}
\mywrite{D}
\mywrite{B}

\immediate\openout\mywritefile=\jobname.zzz
\immediate\write\mywritefile{\the\mywritetoks}
\immediate\closeout\mywritefile
\end{document}
```

Produces

```
A,C,D,B
```

in `\jobname.zzz`